# Protractor -> Chrome Options Error

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

Getting Error:

```
E/launcher - unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
from unknown error: cannot parse mobileEmulation
from unknown error: 'Google Nexus 5' must be a valid device
from unknown error: must be a valid device
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700
```

Protractor configuration:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions': {
                'mobileEmulation': {
                    'deviceName': 'Google Nexus 5'
                }
            }
},
```

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the device name has to be *exactly equal* to a supported device, in this case, specify `Nexus 5` only:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions': {
        'mobileEmulation': {
            'deviceName': 'Nexus 5'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks ! This worked. https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/728  . Protractor Article really messed with me